# Angular routing is not showing the component content

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I created a sample of my project here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-1nftzt)

I implemented the routing in my Angular application. As a part of that I have written the above **Stackblitz**.

On that sample there are two components available:

> 1. Appcomponent
> 2. LoginComponet

By default it should go to the `LoginComponent` whenever we give URL as `/home` then it should render the `AppComponent`.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const appRoutes:Routes=[
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found', pathMatch: 'full' }  
]
```

**App.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2> Hello App component</h2>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But the problem is that by default it is showing the `appcomponent` and `LoginComponet` content in the same page.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Angular inserts components in the `<router-outlet>`, which in your case is inside of the login component. That means that the content of the login component will be shown in addition to the routed component.

Comment: @MikeS. you are correct, but here it is just showing the URL as `/login` but the content is showing the `app.component.html`

Comment: Remove the ` <router-outlet></router-outlet>` & `<app-root></app-root>` from the `login.component.html` and if there is in any other component.html except `app.component.html`. ` <router-outlet></router-outlet>`  Should be only in the `app.component.html`. Check it works now?

Comment: @ng-hobby  I have removed  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in Login component and kept in `app.component.html`. it is showing the login page along with the app.component.html content

Comment: @Jeb Can you add your code to stackblitz ?
It will be easier for people to fork it from there and find the issue.

Comment: @SupunDeSilva I have updated the stackblitz in the question

Comment: @Jeb Totally forgot this. But the answer from `ng-hobby` is the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, based on our comments I got the problem. Remove the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` & `<app-root></app-root>` from the `login.component.html` and if there is in any other `component.html` except on the `app.component.html`.

In your design, Yo have to just have one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the entire application. In the `app.component.html` you have to just have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and nothing else. If you have some other content in `app.component.html` extract them and place into a new component with new route. It should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your Angular application, it launches the root component by default  which corresponds to AppComponent.

Then it loads all the elements of the corresponding html page. As you have content before the `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` it will display them.

You can find a pretty good example on how to add routing into your application [angular TOH](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh)

So you must put nothing in the default component 'AppComponent', and create another component that you will display with your 'home' route.

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: ${new Component} },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
];
```